# JavaFX bad design: Row identity in observable lists behind the TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, observablelist

Suppose I am displaying very long table with [`TableView`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html). Manual says, `TableView`

> is designed to visualize an unlimited number of rows of data

So, since million of rows won't fit the RAM, I would introduce some caching. This means, that `ObservableList#get()` is allowed to return different instances for the same row index.

Is this true?

What about opposite? May I return the same instance for all row indices filled with different data?

I noticed, that this implies some problem with row editing. At which moment should I pass data to the store? Looks like `TableView` never calls `ObservableList#set()` but just mutates obtained instance.

Where to intercept?

**UPDATE**

Also imagine this very big table was updated at server side. Suppose, one million of records were added.

The only way to report about it -- is by firing observable list addition event, while an addition event also contains reference to all added rows. Which is nonsense -- why send data, which is not event displayed?

Comment: No, an observable list is not allowed to return different instances for the same index - after all, it's still a list. I think you are confused with the node virtualization - the `TableView` only has enough nodes to fill it's visible areas, and re-uses these nodes to show the items in the `ObservableList`. I am not familiar enough with the inner workings to provide a full answer, but this seems like a good read: http://fxexperience.com/2009/09/ui-virtualization/

Comment: Inability to return different instances contradicts the claim `TableView` can work with unlimited list.

Comment: Note, that TableView displays observable list. Doesn't matter how many visual nodes TableView has. I am speaking about number of rows of backend data. Suppose 100,000,000 of rows and you will understand it is impossible to return the same instance for each node all the time.

Comment: A `TableView` with 100,000,000 rows would be rather useless. You'll never get to a certain row. Assume you've got a `ScrollBar` for the `TableView` where you can move the handle by 1,000 pixels. Every movement of the handle by 1 pixel would then change the indices of the displayed rows by about +-100,000, so even getting remotely close to a certain row would require very careful navigation with the mouse. After that you'd still need to move by an expected value of 25,000 rows using the arrow keys (assuming the row is chosen uniformly at random)...

Comment: If it is useless. then why JavaFX creators wrote about this useless thing in Javadoc?

Comment: @SuzanCioc You're confusing the data with the nodes, I think. The `ObservableList` that backs the table (the `items`) has the data. Calling `get(index)` with the same index returns the same element. But the table view also has cells, created by its cell factory. These are different objects to the objects referenced in the `items` list. The point is that the cells are far more memory intensive that the data. There are only enough cells to display what is visible, and the mapping between cells and indexes into the `items` will change, e.g., as the user scrolls.

Comment: So the "virtualization" is a different level of optimization to the caching you are talking about. In your scenario, I think you would "simply" need a custom implementation of `ObservableList`; keep track of the "real" size of the list, cache a portion, update the cache if there's a request for a non-cached element, etc. The virtualization of the cells just sits on top of that implementation, creating a separation between the number of (expensive) cells created and the size of the cache in your implementation.

Comment: This is what I am asking: how to implement `ObservableList` for "unlimited" case. Imagine, that element was evicted from cache on next `get()`. Then it will be created again, and it's identity will be different. Also imagine, that cache has size==1. Then elements will be evicted on each get. Or imagine, that instread of cache we keep data in one instance, then identity will be hte same all the time.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting what the Javadocs are saying here. AIUI, they are saying the *design of the table view imposes no limit* on the number of items in the table; i.e. the *view* itself is scalable at essentially constant memory consumption. There are, obviously, still other constraints on the size of the table data - memory limitations will impose constraints on the *model*, for example, and user experience will also impose constraints. A list can't be literally unlimited (what would `size()` return?). "How to implement an observable list with caching" is interesting, though...

Comment: You can't use the latter option: "we keep data in one instance, then identity will be the same all the time". The cells retain a reference to the item they are (currently) displaying; so by modifying the single instance you would corrupt the data in the cells. Other implementations should work.

Comment: @James_D nevertheless, I did this way. Table queries observable list's row each time, which allows me to substitute correct values.

Comment: I would have guessed that doesn't work with "baked-in" editable cell implementations. But just a guess... And of course if you have your own cell implementation you can make sure it works.

Comment: Still think my list implementation rocks though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the intention of the statement in the Javadocs that you quote

> is designed to visualize an unlimited number of rows of data

is meant to imply that the `TableView` imposes no (additional) constraints on the size of the table data: in other words that the view is essentially scalable at a constant memory consumption. This is achieved by the "virtualization": the table view creates cells only for the visible data, and reuses them for different items in the backing list as, e.g., the user scrolls. Since in a typical application the cells (which are graphical) consume far more memory than the data, this represents a big performance saving and allows for as many rows in the table as could feasibly be handled by the user.

There are still, of course, other constraints on the table data size that are not imposed by the table view. The model (i.e. observable list) needs to store the data and consequently memory constraints will (in the default implementation) impose a constraint on the number of rows in the table. You could implement a caching list (see below) to reduce the memory footprint, if needed. And as @fabian points out in the comments below the question, user experience is likely to impose constraints long before you reach that point (I'd recommend using pagination or some kind of filtering).

Your question about identity of elements retrieved from the list is pertinent in a caching implementation: it basically boils down to whether a list implementation is obliged to guarantee `list.get(i) == list.get(i)`, or whether it is enough merely to guarantee `list.get(i).equals(list.get(i))`. To the best of my knowledge, `TableView` only expects the latter, so an implementation of `ObservableList` that caches a relatively small number of elements and recreates them as needed should work.

For proof of concept, here is an implementation of an unmodifiable caching observable list:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.collections.ObservableListBase;

public class CachedObservableList<T> extends ObservableListBase<T> {
    
    private final int maxCacheSize ;
    private int cacheStartIndex ;
    private int actualSize ;
    private final IntFunction<T> generator ;
    
    private final LinkedList<T> cache ;
    
    public CachedObservableList(int maxCacheSize, int size, IntFunction<T> generator) {
        this.maxCacheSize = maxCacheSize ;
        this.generator = generator ;
        
        this.cache = new LinkedList<T>();
        
        this.actualSize = size ;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        
        int debugCacheStart = cacheStartIndex ;
        int debugCacheSize = cache.size(); 
        
        if (index < cacheStartIndex) {
            // evict from end of cache:
            int numToEvict = cacheStartIndex + cache.size() - (index + maxCacheSize);
            if (numToEvict < 0) {
                numToEvict = 0 ;
            }
            if (numToEvict > cache.size()) {
                numToEvict = cache.size();
            }
            cache.subList(cache.size() - numToEvict, cache.size()).clear();
            
            // create new elements:
            int numElementsToCreate = cacheStartIndex - index ;
            if (numElementsToCreate > maxCacheSize) {
                numElementsToCreate = maxCacheSize ;
            }
            cache.addAll(0, 
                    IntStream.range(index, index + numElementsToCreate)
                    .mapToObj(generator)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            
            cacheStartIndex = index ;
            
        } else if (index >= cacheStartIndex + cache.size()) {
            // evict from beginning of cache:
            int numToEvict = index - cacheStartIndex - maxCacheSize + 1 ;
            if (numToEvict < 0) {
                numToEvict = 0 ;
            }
            if (numToEvict >= cache.size()) {
                numToEvict = cache.size();
            }
            
            cache.subList(0, numToEvict).clear();
       
            // create new elements:
            
            int numElementsToCreate = index - cacheStartIndex - numToEvict - cache.size() + 1; 
            if (numElementsToCreate > maxCacheSize) {
                numElementsToCreate = maxCacheSize ;
            }
            
            cache.addAll(
                    IntStream.range(index - numElementsToCreate + 1, index + 1)
                    .mapToObj(generator)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            
            cacheStartIndex = index - cache.size() + 1 ;
        }
        
        try {
            T t = cache.get(index - cacheStartIndex);
            assert(generator.apply(index).equals(t));
            return t ;
        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            System.err.println("Exception retrieving index "+index+": cache start was "+debugCacheStart+", cache size was "+debugCacheSize);
            throw exc ;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return actualSize ;
    }
  
}
```

And here's a quick example using it, that has 100,000,000 rows in the table. Obviously this is unusable from a user experience perspective, but it seems to work perfectly well (even if you change the cache size to be smaller than the number of displayed cells).

```
import java.util.Objects;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CachedTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CachedObservableList<Item> data = new CachedObservableList<>(100, 100_000_000, i -> new Item(String.format("Item %,d",i)));
        
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(data);
        
        TableColumn<Item, String> itemCol = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        itemCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        itemCol.setMinWidth(300);
        table.getColumns().add(itemCol);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(table, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        
        public Item(String name) {
            setName(name) ;
        }
        
        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }
        

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }
        

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o.getClass() != Item.class) {
                return false ;
            }
            return Objects.equals(getName(), ((Item)o).getName());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There's obviously quite a lot more to do if you want to implement the list so that it is modifiable; start by thinking about exactly what behavior you would need for `set(index, element)` if `index` is not in the cache... and then subclass `ModifiableObservableListBase`.

For editing:

> I noticed, that this implies some problem with row editing. At which moment should I pass data to the store? Looks like TableView never calls ObservableList#set() but just mutates obtained instance.

You have three options that I can see:

If your domain objects use JavaFX properties, then the default behavior is to update the property when editing is committed. You can register listeners with the properties and update the backing store if they change.

Alternatively, you can register an `onEditCommit` handler with the `TableColumn`; this will get notified when an edit is committed in the table, and so you could update the store from this. Note that this will replace the default edit commit behavior, so you will also need to update the property. This gives you the opportunity to veto the update to the cached property if the update to the store fails for some reason, and is probably the option you want.

Thirdly, if you implement the editing cells yourself, instead of using default implementations such as `TextFieldTableCell`, you could invoke methods on the model directly from the controls in the cell. This is probably not desirable, as it violates the standard design patterns and avoids the usual editing notifications built into the table view, but it may be a useful option in some cases.

> Also imagine this very big table was updated at server side. Suppose, one million of records were added.
>
> The only way to report about it -- is by firing observable list addition event, while an addition event also contains reference to all added rows.

That's not true, as far as I can tell. `ListChangeListener.Change` has a `getAddedSublist()` method, but the API docs for this state it returns

> a subList view of the list that contains only the elements added

so it should simply return `getItems().sublist(change.getFrom(), change.getTo())`. Of course, this simply returns a sublist view of the cached list implementation, so doesn't create the objects unless you explicitly request them. (Note that `getRemoved()` might potentially cause more problems, but there should be some way to work around that too.)

Finally, to bring this full circle, while the observable list implementation is doing work here of caching the elements and making the model "unlimited" in the number of rows it can support (up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), it wouldn't be possible to use this in the table view if the table view didn't implement "virtualization". A non-virtualized implementation of table view would create cells for each item in the list (i.e. it would call `get(i)` for `0 <= i < items.size()`, creating a cell for each), place the cells in a scroll pane implementation, and the memory consumption would blow up even with the caching in the list. So "unlimited" in the Javadocs really does mean that any limit is deferred to implementation of the model.